# Unknown Error Message on Boot

Tags: boot, 22.04, acpi

I Freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Device. The Operating System seems to work fine so far, but when booting the Device i get the Following Message displayed before the System completely starts:

`[   902.161317] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [ECRM] (0000000001de87dd) [EmbeddedControl] (20210730/evregion-130)`

`[   902.161406] ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20210730/exfldio-261)`

`[   902.161479] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.GPIO.EVT due tp previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210730/psparse-529)`

I am fairly new to Linux and have no idea what this could mean or if it is of importance, but i would like to resolve this, mainly to at least get rid of the Message, even if its not a problem.

**I Thank you for any Help.
Maurice**

Comment: If your system works fine, seeing errors on boot is perfectly normal and nothing you have to worry about. You can (and should) just ignore them.

Comment: This shouldn't be anything important. Unless your system doesn't start.